# Dates in X-axis using pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data from pandas. First I group by weeks and count for each grouped week, them I want to plot for each date, however when I try to plot I get just some dates, not all of them.

I am using the following code:

```
my_data = res1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='d', freq='W-MON')).agg('count').u
p1,  = plt.plot(my_data, '.-')
a = plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

My result is the following:

[image]

I wanted a value in the x-axis for each date in the grouped dataframe.

EDIT: I tried to use `plt.xticks(list(my_data.index.astype(str)), rotation=45)`
The plot I get is the following:
[image: I would like to have the complete dates]

Comment: you can simply put the list of dates you want to display for each point in `plt.xticks(dates)`

Comment: I tried doing that, however instead of having the whole dates I get just the year

Comment: You would benefit from creating a [mcve] of the issue, such that people can give an answer which actually suits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find a working chunk of code below:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

a = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, 99, 10))

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())

plt.plot(pd.date_range(date(2016,1,1), periods=10, freq='D'), a)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If you generate the data with `freq='D'`, using a `DayLocator` is reasonable for ticking each date that occurs in the data. What if the frequency is different? This is what the question asks about as I understand it.

Comment: i wasn't able to make this work, however `plt.xticks(list(my_data.index.astype(str)), list(my_data.index.astype(str)), rotation=45)` worked for me

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest valid point, depending upon the frequency `DayLocator`, `MonthLocator`, `YearLocator` etc had to be used.

Comment: @JorgeRodriguezMolinuevo: your way is must succinct, indeed